# Do plants have preference for the form of nitrogen as nutrient?

Tags: biochemistry, ecology, nutrition

In the nitrogen cycle (ecology), it is usually described that plants can use nitrogen in the form of ammonium (NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup>) and nitrate (NO<sub>3</sub><sup>-</sup>). Do plants prefer one form of nitrogen over the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting verbatim from [this](http://www.kno3.org/product-features-a-benefits/nitrate-no3-versus-ammonium-nh4) site. *The reference is not really a scientific article but you can check the references it cites. Some were not in English so I did not check. However these points are fairly logical*

> Nitrates are the preferred nitrogen source:
>
> - Non-volatile: unlike ammonium, nitrate is non-volatile, so there is    no need to incorporate it in the soil when applied by top- or side dressing, which makes it a convenient source for application.
> - Mobile in the soil - direct uptake by the plant, highest efficiency.
> - Nitrates synergistically promote the uptake of cations, such as K, Ca    and Mg, while ammonium competes for the uptake with these cations.
> - Nitrates can be readily absorbed by the plant and do not need to    undergo any further conversion, as is the case with urea and ammonium, before plant uptake.
> - No acidification of the soil if all the nitrogen is applied as    nitrate-nitrogen.
> - Nitrates limit the uptake of harmful elements, such as chloride, into    large quantities.
> - The conversion of nitrates to amino acids occurs in the leaf. This    process is fuelled by solar energy, which makes it an energy-efficient process. Ammonium has to be converted into organic N compounds in the roots. This process is fuelled by carbohydrates, which are at the expense of other plant life processes, such as plant 
>     growth and fruit fill.

Many plants can carry out nitrification but this is not universal. From [this](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.py.12.090174.001035) article:

> Nitrification is sometimes considered so universal and rapid that
>   applications of NH<sub>4</sub>-N are considered equivalent to
>   NO<sub>3</sub>-N. This is not true in many forest, orchard, and
>   grassland soils.

However, nitrate being more soluble is susceptible to leaching and wash off, care has to be taken when using nitrate based fertilizers. From the previously mentioned paper:

> Unlike the positively charged ammonium ion, which is relatively
>   stationary because of its adsorption to organic matter or clay
>   particles, the negatively charged nitrate ion is freely mobile in the
>   soil solution (166). Thus, leaching and denitrification primarily
>   involve a loss of NO<sub>3</sub>-N (171). Inhibition or retardation of
>   nitrification of applied NH<sub>4</sub>-N can reduce nitrogen losses,
>   increase efficiency of applied N, and establish a predominantly
>   ammoniacal form of nitrogen available for plant uptake (105, 171,222,
>   232).

Comment: @quibble Ammonium can at high concentrations even be toxic to plant (roots). This is not uncommon in aquatic peat vegetation.